# Java Swing: disable typeahead for JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have an application that uses JDialog popups.  I'm using 1.6 (compatibility requirement for the customer.)  The ENTER key dismisses the dialog, taking previous results.  The problem is that the user can type-ahead on hitting the ENTER key (or any other text for that matter).

Here's a snippet:

```
private void promptForCredentials(final GenericSwitch sw) {
    final JDialog jd = new JDialog();
    jd.setModal(true);
    jd.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    final JLabel l_user = new JLabel("Username: ");
    final JLabel l_pass = new JLabel("Password: ");
    final JTextField tf_user = new JTextField(25);
    final JTextField tf_pass = new JPasswordField(25);
    JButton b_ok = new JButton("OK");
    JButton b_same = new JButton("Same as previous");
    JButton b_cancel = new JButton("Cancel");

    final JLabel l_authfail = new JLabel("Authentication failed, try again.");

    ActionListener okSameListener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            // if (((JButton) ev.getSource()).isVisible()) {
            //     return;  // always returns for 'OK' button!
            // }
            String name = ((JButton) ev.getSource()).getText();
            if (name.equals("OK")) {
                // If user hits OK, save user/pw, unless they're both empty
                // (treat that as "use last")
                if (! tf_user.getText().isEmpty()
                        && ! tf_pass.getText().isEmpty()) { 
                    mLastUsername = tf_user.getText();
                    mLastPassword = tf_pass.getText();
                }
            }
            jd.dispose();

            sw.setUsername(mLastUsername, true);
            sw.setPassword(mLastPassword, true);
            if (!sw.checkLogin()) {
                // auth failed so don't save for next time
                mLastUsername = "";
                mLastPassword = "";
            }
            display(sw.mIndex);
            poll();
        }
    };

    b_ok.addActionListener(okSameListener);
    b_same.addActionListener(okSameListener);
    b_cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            System.out.print("Poll cancelled\n");
            abort();
            jd.dispose();
        }
    });

    Box box0 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    Box box1 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    Box box2 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    Box box3 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    box0.add(l_authfail);
    box1.add(l_user);
    box1.add(tf_user);
    box2.add(l_pass);
    box2.add(tf_pass);

    box3.add(b_ok);
    box3.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
    if (!mLastUsername.isEmpty() && !mLastPassword.isEmpty()) {
        box3.add(b_same);
        box3.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
    }
    box3.add(b_cancel);

    if (sw.authFailed()) {
        jd.add(box0);
    }
    jd.add(box1);
    jd.add(box2);
    jd.add(box3);
    SwingUtilities.getRootPane(b_ok).setDefaultButton(b_ok);
    jd.setTitle("Login for " + sw.mShortname);
    jd.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));
    jd.setSize(new Dimension(400, 150));
    jd.setLocationRelativeTo(getContentPane());
    jd.setVisible(true);
}
```

Since this app polls a number of external resources, most of which usually have the same username/pw, it's nice to just hit "enter" to cycle through the lot, the first time.  All good.  (And yeah, I know I should have "use same for subsequent" checkbox.  Maybe later.)

However, I noticed to my surprise that I can type ahead.  Frankly, I like this, but I don't think it's really appropriate for general users.  How can I disable it?

Would it work to consume all actions prior to setting the JDialog visible?  I tried checking if the button is visible, but while the Cancel button is, the OK button isn't!  (commented out above)

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I'm not 100% sure what your exact problem is. If you don't get a decent solution soon, consider describing it in more detail including your observed vs expected behaviors.

Comment: Thanks for looking, @HovercraftFullOfEels.  What I want is for any text typed after ENTER (or clicking OK) to be discarded, until the next popup appears -- disallowing typeahead.  However, the more I think about it, accidental incorrect type-ahead for my particular application won't cause any harm (it'll just ask again if creds are wrong).  So, the question is now hypothetical rather than practical.

Comment: BTW, I see from searching that while type-ahead is retained in SE 1.6, it's lost in 1.7.